# IPX/SPX on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows XP 32 bit system, which I used to connect to my Novell Netware 3.1x server, which is a database server.

Now I am planning to migrate from Windows XP to Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit), but the issue is that Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't support the IPX\SPX protocol.

Is there any workaround to make IPX protocol work in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: You cannot be serious..

Comment: What kind of database service is being run on that box anyway?

Comment: After all this why the heck would you care to upgrade the CLIENT to w2k8r2 that makes no sense at all.

Comment: The only logical answer to this would be a security issue on the xp client, is that correct?

Comment: @tonyroth Security?  From the same place running a twenty year old server?  I'm having trouble seeing that.  Wait unless... is *security-through-obsolescence* a real thing?

Comment: @HopelessN00b lol, yes nothing about this makes sense.

Comment: Actually netware with ipx/spx was pretty secure!  Really curious as to what DB nlm he is running.

Comment: @tonyroth  Yeah not digging on Netware, but any system that's gone 20 years without an update is just not secure.

Comment: Server UTIL halted Friday, March 8, 2002   9:06:53 pm
Abend 1 on P00: Server-5.60a-1937: CPU Hog Detected by Timer

Registers:
    CS = 0008 DS = 0010 ES = 0010 FS = 0010 GS = 0010 SS = 0010
    EAX = FCE17318 EBX = 00000000 ECX = 00000000 EDX = 00000040
    ESI = D5968AA0 EDI = D5968AE0 EBP = D5A6780C ESP = D7B45D5C
    EIP = 00000000 FLAGS = 00000002


Running process: BTRIEVE.NLM     2 Process
Thread Owned by NLM: BTRIEVE.NLM

Comment: yep btrieve forgot about that one! And you could go 20 years without an update on netware 3.1 and it would be still secure... from current attack vectors.

Answer (score 7):

The workaround would be to configure the Netware server for TCP/IP and drop IPX/SPX. It's 2013! This will probably involve an upgrade, but that Netware 3.1 server is **twenty** years old now.

Comment: Or run Netware Gateway Services on an NT 4.0 box!

Comment: NT 4.0 is just 17 years old, so there seems plenty of headroom before it hits the magical 20... BTW: gateway services for netware were [available with Windows 2000 Server too](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121394/en-us).

Comment: But for ultimate fun, I would advise deploying on NT 4.0

Comment: All snark aside, turning on TCP/IP on the NW3.1 server is likely your only choice with Server 2008. Both Btrieve and the Oracle version that runs on Netware of that vintage have TCP/IP support. It isn't great support, but it is there. Novell itself abandoned IPX many years ago, so Microsoft felt justified removing support.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  [From this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/12cbaf3b-9b45-408b-8222-62a0e0121209/):

```
 IPX/SPX has been officially removed from windows server system since
 2008.

 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753256(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_6



 But based on my experience , here is workaround that install this
 protocol for server 2008 :



 1.       Cope files of path below from server 2003 to same path on server 2008:

 ·         Windows\System32\drivers(nwlnkipx.sys,nwlnkspx.sys)

 ·         Windows\inf(netnwlnk.inf)

 ·         Windows\System32(wshisn.dll,nwprovau.dll)

 2.       perform install new protocol steps on 2008, and you can found that IPX/SPX is listed in viable protocol list.
```

Being 32 bit drivers, I'm not sure what problems you'll run into on a natively 64 bit OS, but this is a workaround, so I guess issues are not unexpected.

(Having posted that, you really should do like Mark suggested and let obsolete technology rest in peace.)

Comment: I have already tried that way... once coping those file from a XP 64 bit and another time from Win 2003 server 64 bit..and then tried to install the IPX/SPX protocol, but windows keep on saying as digitally unsigned drivers and even though its does get installed, but its properties tab is grayed out

Comment: @AnvinAbraham Then it looks like you need to upgrade the Netware server to use TCP/IP.  Or, you know, replace it with a server running an operating system that's actually used anymore.  I hear good things about a spunky new start-up called Microsoft, as well as some Scandinavian guy named Linus who's started experimenting with writing his own GNU/Unix-like kernel.

Comment: @AnvinAbraham you would need to [disable driver signature enforcement](http://www.thegeekprofessor.com/tips-and-tricks/hacks/windows7/turn-off-driver-signing-enforcement-in-windows-7/) to get the drivers loaded at all.

Comment: I tried to install after disabling driver signature enforcement, but with same result..